Generating White Noise with `rnorm()` vs. `arma.sim()` in R
I’ve been working on generating white noise for a statistical task and found that the rnorm() function in R is a straightforward way to create it. Here’s a simple snippet I used:
# Set the number of samples
n <- 1000

# Generate white noise with mean 0 and variance 1
white_noise <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

# View the first 10 values
head(white_noise, 10)

# Plot the generated white noise
plot(white_noise, type = "l", main = "White Noise", xlab = "Index", ylab = "Value")

This code generates a white noise series with a mean of 0 and a variance of 1. It’s quite effective for basic tasks.
However, I’ve also seen references to the arma.sim() function for generating white noise. I’m curious how this function compares to rnorm() and whether it offers any advantages for my task. Could someone explain how to use arma.sim() for generating white noise (with a mean of 0 and a variance of 1)?

Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.

Your question verges on being a programming-only question (which would make it off-topic at CV), but I think the question is more directed to the statistical assumptions built around the functions. The core idea is that the rnorm() function is generating pure noise, which can be adjusted for it's mean and SD. The arima.sim() function is different in that it can generate auto-correlated error instead (which can be relevant to time series or clustered data such as repeated measurements). So if your goal is to simulate data that has some auto-correlation built into the data, then arima.sim() is better for that purpose. Below I show two examples that are made clear with plotting the autocorrelation function (ACF).
#### Set Seed and Parameters ####
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
b0 <- 50
b1 <- 25

#### Simulate Random Noise Only ####
e <- rnorm(n)
x1 <- rnorm(n)
y1 <- b0 + b1*x1 + e
fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)

#### Simulate Autocorrelation ####
ar.epsilon <- arima.sim( # simulates time series
  list( # list to store info
    order = c(1,0,0), # simple AR(1) model with no differencing, etc.
    ar = 0.7 # level of autocorrelation
  ),
  n = n, # number of observations
  sd=10 # fluctuation
)

x2 <- rnorm(n) # normally distributed x
y2 = b0 + b1*x2 + ar.epsilon # intercept, slope, and autocorrelated residuals
fit2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2)

#### Plot ACFs ####
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(resid(fit1),main="Random Noise")
acf(resid(fit2),main="Autocorrelation")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

You can see the plots show clearly that the second fit generated with arima.sim() error is highly autocorrelated:

